# Подключение флешки только на чтение

Tags: python, windows, usb, mount, readonly

Как на питоне на винде программно смаунтить флешку с опцией readonly? Например, флешка стоит по пути `F:`, надо сделать так, чтобы нельзя было на неё ничего писать, только читать.

Answer (score 2):

Можно вызвать внешнюю утилиту `diskpart.exe` с командой `attr disk set readOnly`. Работает, но надеюсь есть вариант получше.